# Wbsite refresh with php or JS

Tags: javascript, php

how can I refresh my PHP website so that my time (time in seconds) will update constantly without a reloading animation/screen?
I tried a bit but with these codes I always had a reload animation!
(Reload animation = short white screen on reloading  a page)

Comment: so... what exactly are you trying to do? (sharing the code is a good start)

Comment: You're looking for Ajax, with a timer that runs it every x seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refresh the current page use

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

Or if you want to go on different page use

```
header("Refresh:0; url=page2.php");
```

To set the interval for refreshing, replace 0 with time you want in seconds.

Edited as per asker requirements

Let name this file timer.php

```
    <?php
        echo microtime(true);
    ?>
```

And This is the javascript function that fetch time from php file and update it in html without reloading

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

        function updateTime(){
            var xhttp = null;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{
                xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(this.readyState == 4 &amp;&amp; this.status == 200){
                    document.getElementById('n1').innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };

            xhttp.open("GET","path/to/timer.php",true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: If I do that, the Website Icon would be shown and there is always a loading circle at the website icon

Comment: @JackboyPlay JackCraft So when you want refresh the page. If there is some condition put this code in if...else. And don't forget to accept answer if it solve your problem.

Comment: How can I make it that only the current time is updating the oter things not? (mysql, e.g)

Comment: Did you mean to refresh this page only one time. @JackboyPlay JackCraft

Comment: I mean whether it is possible to refresh a echo ''; or a specified part

Comment: @JackboyPlay JackCraft Yes it is possible but you need to implement it using AJAX if you do not want to reload the whole page. Otherwise you can just change the content and reload page to change its content.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @JackboyPlay JackCraft try this https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: But I want to reload this line constantly: echo '<br><name id=n1>' . microtime(true) . '</name>'; And I want that It updates automaticly and not on click

Comment: On what time interval you want to reload this. @JackboyPlay JackCraft

Comment: Each second or each 2

Comment: Okay got it. Wait for a while

Comment: @JackboyPlay JackCraft I updated answer

Comment: How can I do it if I have php variables in time.php from indes.php?

Comment: To pass data to time.php modify xhttp.open("GET","path/to/timer.php",true); to xhttp.open("GET","path/to/timer.php?key=value",true); and add this line in the beginning of time.php $data = $_GET['key'];

Comment: @JackboyPlay JackCraft See this https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp